# Reappend a removed item in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am populating a separate list with items from a bunch of checkboxes using jQuery.

I am able to append and remove the list items if there is a check or uncheck. 
The issue I am having is when I use the .remove(), if I try to go and re-append a list item, there is no action. The list item does not get re-appended.

Below is my jQuery I am using, but what would be logic to get it to re-append after a list item has been removed.

```
   $('#attendeePicker .zInput.zCheckbox ,#attendeePicker2 .zInput.zCheckbox').on("click", function(e) {
            var parentSection = $(this).parents("section").attr("id");


            var attendeename = $(this).find('input').data("attendeename"),
                productname = $(this).find('input').data("productname"),
             optionprice = $(this).find('input').data("optionprice"),
                /* get jQuery selector for list from data */
                //jQId = "#" + data.,
                $list = $(".CartList li." + attendeename).find('.itemList');
            //alert($list)


            if ($(this).hasClass("zSelected")) {
                /* add element to list if selelected*/

                var li = '<li class="animated bounceIn"><span class="itemTime">' + $("#" + parentSection + " .timelist .zInput.zSelected input").val() + ' - ' + '</span><span class="itemName">' + productname + '</span><span class="itemPrice">' + optionprice + '</span></li>';
                //  var li = '<li class="animated bounceIn"><span class="itemTime">' + $(".timelist .zInput.zSelected input").val() + ' - ' + '</span><span class="itemName">' + productname + '</span><span class="itemPrice">' + optionprice + '</span></li>';

                $list.append(li);

            } else {
                /* empty list if unchecked*/

                //Empties the ilist BUT we don't want that.
                // $list.empty(); // completely empties the list
                $list.remove(li);  //only removes the single item. I want this.

            }

        });
```

Comment: Unrelated issue, to check if checkbox is checked you can simply do $(this).is(':checked')

Comment: Tried `.detach()` ? http://api.jquery.com/detach/ _"The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time"_

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an element it is removed from the DOM so you cannot re append it.

You can do it in following ways :

**Method 1**

Clone the element ([.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)) first and then remove it. Use the cloned object to re-append.

WORKING SAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/pvod0gam/1/

```
var $elem;
$("#check").click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
        $elem = $("#elem").clone();
        $("#elem").remove();
    }else{
        $("body").append($elem);
    }
});
```

**Method 2**

Toggle display of the element ([.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)). Basically show/hide on checkbox state.

WORKING SAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/9mfv67gq/

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    $("#elem").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just .hide() and .show() the sub list based on the checkbox that you are checking/unchecking.